# A basis of subspace defined by non-homogenous equation, that is, Ax = b

Tags: homogeneous-equation, projection-matrices

I know that if I have an equation of the form $ax + by + cz = 0$, I can calculate the basis in $R^3$. For example if I have a linear equation $x - 2y + 5z = 0$, then from mu understanding the basis are ${(2,1,0)(1,-2,-1)}$.

But now, let say I have a system of non homogeneous equation

$x - 2y + 5z = 4$,

$3x + 1.1 y + 2z = 7$

How can I find the basis of this system? Do I have to find the basis of the homogeneous form of the equation? Then what is the role of the constant terms on LHS?

From my understanding, the constant terms just provide the bias or shift to the basis from the origin but still I cannot wrap my head around this!

My ultimate goal is to project a circle or an ellipse on this surface. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: A basis is something a vector space has. The solutions of a non-homogeneous system do not form a vector space, so they do not have a basis. BUT if you can find a single solution $v$ of the inhomogeneous system, then every solution of the inhomogeneous system is of the form $v+c_1u_1+\cdots+c_ru_r$, where $u_1,\dots,u_r$ is a basis for the set of solutions of the corresponding homogeneous system.

Comment: Anything to say?

Comment: I am very sorry for the late response. 
I understand your explanation but suppose I form a basis of the homogeneous part of the equation and then project a vector on it, then how are the constant terms on RHS effecting this projection?

Let's say I have vector centered at $(3,-7)$  with  $x1-x2=2$. The basis of the homogeneous part is $[1;1]$ with projection matrix $P=[0.5 0.5;0.5 0.5]$. The projection of the vector results in $(-2,-2)$ thus following the homogeneous equation but not the constant part. Now how will the constant term effect my answer or how can I incorporate it in basis?

Comment: I hope you understand my difficulty now!

Comment: I *think* what you are trying to do in your example is to project the vector $(3,-7)$ onto the line $x_1-x_2=2$. One way is to move everything so the line goes through the origin; for example, move vector and line two units to the left, so you are projecting $(1,-7)$ onto $x_1-x_2=0$. The projection is $(-3,-3)$. Then move it back two units to the right, to $(-1,-3)$, and there's your projection. Is that what you want?

Comment: What if I have an ellipse with mean $(3,-7)$ and co variance $[3 1;1 4]$, do I have to move the mean an line only?

Also if I have two equations with constant terms $a,b$, then I have to move by $a+b$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the mean and covariance of an ellipse. If you have, say, $ax+by+cz=r$ and $dx+ey+fz=s$, then you have to shift (at least) two of the variables, say, $x$ and $y$, to get  $ax'+by'+cz=0$ and $dx'+ey'+fz=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This discussion was very helpful.